# How to add multiple Sentences (which are stored in a list) into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I would like to create an aspect analysis from user reviews. The reviews contain various aspects and therefore the reviews need to be separated into sentences. I save the data in a pandas dataframe and separate the sentences with the nltk library.

I put the separate sentences in a list that I want to format into a dataframe and connect to the original dataframe. However, I get an error. Instead of an extra column, I get 19 new columns. (the individual sentences are not stored in a cell, I think every single sentence gets their own column) I also tested itertools but I also get a wrong record.

Can someone help me to get the right format?

I would like to have a new dataframe which looks like that:

```
U_REVIEW                                                                                      | SENTENCES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Im a Sentence. Iam another Sentence in a Row.                                                 |[u'Im a Sentence', u'Iam another Sentence in a Row.']
Here we go, next Sentence. Blub, more blubs.                                                  |[u"Here weg o, next Sentence.", u'Blub, more blubs.']
Once again, more Sentence. And some other information. The Restaurant was ok, but not awesome.|[u"Once again, more Sentence.", u'And some other information.',u’The Restaurant was ok, but not awesome.’]
```

That’s how my code looks like:

```
ta = ta[['U_REVIEW']]

Output:
U_REVIEW
Im a Sentence. Iam another Sentence in a Row.
Here we go, next Sentence. Blub, more blubs.
Once again, more Sentence. And some other information. The Restaurant was ok, but not awesome.

# the empty lists
sentences = []
ss = []

for sentence in ta['U_REVIEW']:
    # seperates the review into sentence
    sentence = sent_tokenize(sentence)
    sentences.append(sentence)
    test = itertools.chain(sentences)

#new dataframe to add the Sentences
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sentences)

#create Column
cols2 = ['REVIEW_SENTENCES']

# bring the two dataframes together
df2 = pd.DataFrame(sentences, columns=cols2)



Output of senteces:
[[u'Im a Sentence', u'Iam another Sentence in a Row.'],[u"Here weg o, next     Sentence.", u'Blub, more blubs.'],[u"Once again, more Sentence.", u'And some other information.',u’The Restaurant was ok, but not awesome.’]]

Output of test:
<itertools.chain object at 0x000000001316DC18>

Output and Information of the new Dataframe df2:
AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 19 columns

U_REVIEW                                                                                      | 0                        | 1                             | 2 ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Im a Sentence. Iam another Sentence in a Row.                                                 |Im a Sentence             |Iam another Sentence in a Row. | 
Here we go, next Sentence. Blub, more blubs.                                                  |Here we go, next Sentence.|Blub, more blubs.              |
Once again, more Sentence. And some other information. The Restaurant was ok, but not awesome.|Once again, more Sentence.|And some other information.    |The Restaurant was ok, but not awesome.
```

Here is a Testset of a Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
ta = pd.DataFrame( ['Im a Sentence. Iam another Sentence in a Row','Here we go, next Sentence. Blub, more blubs.','Once again, more Sentence. And some other information. The Restaurant was ok, but not awsome.'])
ta.columns =['U_REVIEW']
```

Comment: can you add sample of raw data.

Comment: I added a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this I have done it in python 3.5 I think it should work for 2.5 also:

```
In [45]: df = pd.DataFrame(ta.U_REVIEW.str.split('.',expand=True).replace('',np.nan).fillna(np.nan).values.flatten()).dropna()

In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
                                         0
0                            Im a Sentence
1            Iam another Sentence in a Row
4                Here we go, next Sentence
5                         Blub, more blubs
8                Once again, more Sentence
9               And some other information
10   The Restaurant was ok, but not awsome
```

is this what you want:

```
ta.U_REVIEW.str.split('.',expand=True)
Out[50]: 
                           0                               1  \
0              Im a Sentence   Iam another Sentence in a Row   
1  Here we go, next Sentence                Blub, more blubs   
2  Once again, more Sentence      And some other information   

                                        2     3  
0                                    None  None  
1                                          None  
2   The Restaurant was ok, but not awsome
```

or

```
In [52]: ta.U_REVIEW.str.split('.').apply(list)
Out[52]: 
0      [Im a Sentence,  Iam another Sentence in a Row]
1     [Here we go, next Sentence,  Blub, more blubs, ]
2    [Once again, more Sentence,  And some other in...
Name: U_REVIEW, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks but its not totaly what i need. I thought about putting the sentences in a list and store it in a row. on the next row the same. split the sentences and add them in a list and store it in the pandas df. Just like i showed it on the first example (Column: Sentences)

Comment: @Nika you want one column for each sentence is that right?

Comment: Yes. I would like to have 1 new column with the whole Review but splitted into sentences in a list. But I dont know if this is possible. So I would like to have in one Row this Result: [u'Im a Sentence', u'Iam another Sentence in a Row.'] (this would be row position 0)